# Commands for breakpoints in a .pdbrc file

Tags: python, debugging

I'd like to save the commands for a breakpoint in a `.pdbrc`, something like:

```
b 81 
commands 1 
pp foo.attr1 
pp foo.attr2 
end 
b 108 
commands 2 
pp bar.attr1 
pp bar.attr2 
end
```

This would automate setting the environment for the debugging session. However, this does not work with `python -m pdb script.py`, because at the line `commands 1`, the pdb prompt starts and asks me for the commands for the first breakpoint, ignoring what I wrote in `.pdbrc`; further, it raises a `NameError` after I type `end` at the pdb prompt, because of `foo.attr1`, `foo.attr2` and even `end`. The same happens for the rest of the breakpoints, so I end up with them set but not their commands.

What would be the correct way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm struggling with this...were you able to do it?

Comment: This should now be fixed. See: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/110496

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that the command must be defined on one line:

```
commands 1;; pp foo.attr1;; pp foo.attr2;; end;;
```

However, it appears that this will only work at the prompt, and you will incorrectly get:

```
Usage : commands [bnum]
        ...
        end
```

if you place the line above in a .pdbrc

Looking at [pdb.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pdb.py) it appears that the author does not properly handle defining commands in a pdbrc.

I personally would just temporarily place the print lines in the code I was debugging while using pdbrc to save the breakpoints of interest to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want this set every time you use pdb anywhere. My recommendation would be to set up an alias, such as:

```
alias setup_myproj b 81;; commands 1;; pp foo.attr1;; pp foo.attr2;; end
```

Then you can run `setup_myproj` when appropriate.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to set this in a local .pdbrc file without an alias. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands): "If a file .pdbrc exists in the user’s home directory or in the current directory, [...]. If both files exist, the one in the home directory is read first and aliases defined there can be overridden by the local file."

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Looks like this is solved now with [PR 110496](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/110496)

ORIGINAL:

More than ten years later, but, unfortunately, it looks like `pdb` still does not properly handle the `end` command when reading `commands` from a `.pdbrc` file. There's now a related [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90095) for cpython.

In the meantime, *for simple control flows*, it may be possible to work around the issue, simply by *not* using the `commands` command. For example, you could do:

```
# set the breakpoints
b 81 
b 108 
# continue to the first breakpoint
continue 
# execute commands at first breakpoint
pp foo.attr1 
pp foo.attr2 
# continue to the second breakpoint
continue
# execute commands at second breakpoint
pp bar.attr1 
pp bar.attr2
...
```

Obviously this only works in simple cases where you know which breakpoint will be reached next.

Answer (score 0):

This is still unsolved today (June 2023), here is what worked for me:

```
$ echo 'run;; b 81;; cont;; pp foo.attr1;;' | python3 -m pdb main.py
```

Alternatively, put the commands in `commands.txt` (as a single line) and run:

```
$ cat commands.txt | python3 -m pdb main.py
```