# Add commands to a breakpoint in .pdbrc

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Is it possible to specify commands for a breakpoint in a `.pdbrc` file?

I tried this in my `.pdbrc`:

```
break myscript.py:1
commands 1
!print('hello, world!')
continue
```

But when I run `python -m pdb myscript.py`, I am prompted to enter the commands interactively, instead of them being set from `.pdbrc`:

```
>>> python -m pdb myscript.py
Breakpoint 1 at myscript.py:1
(com)
```

Only after I enter the commands does `pdb` finish executing the `.pdbrc`:

```
(com) continue
hello, world!
# Script runs
```

Obviously this severely constrains what kind of automated debugging setup is possible with the `.pdbrc` file. Is there a solution?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2013698