# Python (pdb) How to use the use the "commands" command in a .pdbrc file or -c command

Tags: python, command, pdb

I have a python file:

```py
def do_something():
    pass

def main():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = a+b
    print(f"c:{c}")
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run this command:

```
python -m pdb -c "b 5" -c "commands 1\ndo_something()\nend" -c "c" main.py
```

It doesn't work.

And I have a .pdbrc file

```
b 5
commands 1
do_something()
end
c
```

It doesn't work either.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you can specify multiple `-c` options; when I try, it seems to only execute the first. Also, you can't use `\n` to separate commands in a `-c` string (though if your shell is Bash, you could use `-c $'print("poo")\nprint("moo")'` where the `$'...'` string is interpreted by the shell, and any backslash sequences are parsed and replaced by literal characters).

Comment: @tripleee Thank you very much for your reply, `-c` can be used many times, you can try this `python -m pdb -c "print('poo')" -c "print('moo')" -c "c"` .The problem now is that there is no way to use the `commands` command through `-c` or `.pdbrc` files

Comment: Oh nvm, II was examining it without `pdb` but it seems it has its own use for this option.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68227788, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2013698

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90095

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed for python 3.13 and appears to be back ported to 3.11 and 3.12 per the discussion on this pull request

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90095#issuecomment-1989517207